# Javascript replacing function (Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I guess what I need is regular expression.

lets say I have a var containing the following text:

```
var texty_texy = "Title:<br />Hey there,<br />I'm a simple text.";
```

How do I determine if there is a `"Title:<br />"` in my var (ofcourse "Title" could be changed to `"Tuna:<br />"` or anything)
and how do I replace it with:

```
<div class='title'>Title:</div>Hey there,<br />I'm a simple text.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups in your Regular expression by surrounding parts with ().

That means that it will match only if all of parts where found, but also will save results. So /^(\w*)(:)/ will search for Title: and will split in on $1 = Title and $2 = `:<br />`. But in case when you need to capture only one part then you can use simplified expression: /^(\w*):/

Then while replacing you can use this variables to add then to resuls by adding $1 or $2 into text.

```
var text = "Title:<br />Hey there,<br />I'm a simple text.";

var result = text.replace(/^(\w*):<br \/>/g, "<div class='title'>$1:</div>");
```

Result is:

```
<div class='title'>Title:</div>Hey there,<br />I'm a simple text.
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted.
a script to determine if there is something that looks like the pattern of a title ("Text:<br />", "Hi:<br />")

Comment: No need to capture the br tag, you can remove the parenthesis surrounding it. But this will work.

Comment: but my title doesn't nessaseraly going to be "Title", but the ":<br />" is always going to be there in the var.

Comment: That's what I need! - but I got "Unexpected quantifier"

Comment: I believe `:` should have a backslash before it: `\:`

Comment: No, I think it should not.